# Null values are storing mysql

Tags: java, mysql, null

Null values are storing while I'm trying save data from html fields using servlets.

I have taken to fields but both the fields are saving null to table.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Db_Connections {

    static UserDetails userdetails = new UserDetails();

    //static Connection conn=null;

    public static Connection conn() {
        Connection conn=null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skyhacker","root","root");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static boolean insert_query(UserDetails userdetails2) {
        try {
            Connection conn =Db_Connections.conn();

            PreparedStatement pstmt_insert = conn.prepareStatement("insert into userdata values(?,?,?)");

            pstmt_insert.setInt(1 , userdetails.getId() );
            pstmt_insert.setString(2, userdetails.getName());
            pstmt_insert.setString(3, userdetails.getEmail());
            pstmt_insert.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Delete the static variable `static UserDetails userdetails = new UserDetails();` and you should see where your error is: You are ignoring the argument `UserDetails userdetails2` that you pass into your insert_query method

Answer (score 0):

The param for method `insert_query` is `userdetails2`. But when you insert data into database, you get data from `userdetails`. So change `userdetails` to `userdetails2` and try it.